# Database not working with cloned laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have a project developed in laravel. Now i wanted to create another project in laravel so i copied all to new directory and changed database in env file. Porject in running but database is not changed. It is showing old projects database values. Any mistake i did ??

Answer (score 2):

```
php artisan config:cache
```

When you make changes in the env file you must configure your cache so the changes are loaded otherwise you load the old ones.

Comment: Thanks @pr1nc3. It works. I did cache:clear but did not run config:cache. Thanks Again

Comment: Glad i helped you. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted for future users to see as well.